# how to update json array in java with existing json array value using java. Value are not updating in external json file

Tags: java, json

JSON file:
[
{
"name":"John",
"city":"Berlin",
"job":"Teacher"
},
{
"name":"Mark",
"city":"Oslo",
"job":"Doctor"
}
]

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("F:\file.json"));

```
    for (Object o : a) {
        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

        String name = (String) person.get("name");
        
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("john")) {
            String name1 = (String) person.get("name");
            System.out.println("name1" + name1);

            String city1 = (String) person.get("city");
            System.out.println("city1" + city1);

            String job1 = (String) person.get("job");
            System.out.println("job1" + job1);  
            
            person.put("city", "BLR");
            String city2 = (String) person.get("city");
            System.out.println("city2" + city2);
        }
    }
```

Value are not updating in Json external file

Comment: Save the json file for it to get updated, you just changed the value of an object not in the local file

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is a represent of json that does not link to originally file.
To rewrite file you need to change values in `person` and write it to file.

```
person.put("city", "BLR");
String jsonString = person.toString();
// write jsonString to file
```